# Unable to patch League of Legends in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: games

I've been continuously trying to play LoL through PoL (v4.2.9) and have been unable to thus far.

Installation runs smoothly. then the launcher appears, and every single time it reaches 52%, the launcher crashes. I restart it, begins at 34%,and it crashes yet again at 52%.

Considering I'm still a greenhorn at Ubuntu, I find myself at a loss. How would one fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue a lot. I worked around it this way:

1. Quit League of Legends.
2. Open PlayOnLinux, select *Configure* then select the LoL drive.
3. Navigate to the *Wine* tab.
4. Click *Kill processes* and wait for PlayOnLinux to complete the process (a window will pop up for a short time).
5. Click *Windows reboot* and again wait for it to complete.
6. Start League of Legends.

Also make sure that you are using a compatible Wine version. The one installed by PoL, *1.7.44-LeagueOfLegends2*, should work. Make sure it is selected in the *General* tab. If the patcher still doesn't work, remove the POL virtual drive and reinstall LoL in a new virtual drive using the builtin installer script.

Comment: I've tried this and I still receive the error (at 55% this time). Also, the only option in the Wine versions is 1.7.52-LeagueOfLegends5. As for your second recommendation of removing the virtual drive and reinstalling in a new one, well, I'm not sure how to do that. I apologize.

Comment: Updating! I didn't realize I could simply import the 1.7.44-LeagueOfLegends2 but figured it out. Thank you SO much for helping as the update finished it one slam and the play button is bright and shining. Many thanks, happy Thanksgiving, Merry Christmas, and wonderful New Years along with any other holidays!